If the first ever reserve asset transfer from asset hub to a parachain is of an asset other than DOT it fails with LocalExecutionIncomplete
I've noticed that if the first ever reserve asset transfer from asset hub to a parachain is of an asset other than DOT it fails with LocalExecutionIncomplete, the chopsitcks logs don't show any output. The reserve asset transfer works, after performing a reserve asset transfer of only DOT.
Please note that the account that I'm performing the reserve asset transfer to already exists.
This is the call I'm performing:
0x1f0203010100b52003000101008eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a480308000002043205d8000700e8764817000100000700e876481701000000

It was because you try to transfer a non-exist asset (54) on AssetHub.
The first step of reserve transfer is transfer assets from your sender account to the dest chain sovereign account (This account is on sender chain), and this step is local transfer, no cross chain.
So check these points:
1.The asset is registered on AssetHub
2.The balance which you want to transfer from is sufficient
3.If the dest chain sovereignAccount doesn't have ED or minBalance, the amount you want to transfer should greater than ED and minBalance.
Here I suggest you to check if the dest chain(2093) sovereignAccount(13cKp88oDcoVt3Kn5GeKc2HvsDNAuiuNX59WdHtoFj8rEwGs) have the ED balance, and the minBalance of asset(54)

I had created asset 54 on the chopsticks forked asset hub chain

@Sebastian Check the update. You should transfer some DOT to the sovereign account to make the account exist on chain.

Thanks! So just to confirm, its working as expected? The initial DOT transfer is required?

Yeah, you should transfer >0.1 DOT to the 2093 sovereignAccount (on AssetHub is 13cKp88oDcoVt3Kn5GeKc2HvsDNAuiuNX59WdHtoFj8rEwGs).

0x1f0203010100b52003000101008eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a480308000002043205011f00a10f00010000419c01000000 is succeed.

https://assethub-polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/6130682-2
